# why does it turn square when i merge vertices on a circular surface

Tags: modeling, mesh

When I merge two vertices, it turns into some kind of corner. I don't know how to explain it but yeah.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is the expected behaviour under Subdivision.. that is the curvature interpolated on the new location of the vertex, moved from the smaller cylinder. Did you mean to create a new edge between the vertices (shortcut: F), instead of merging them? Or if you mean to create a smooth connection all the way round, the profile will become less square as you merge the others in the circumference.

Comment: No, I meant to merge them together.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not quite clear from your question.. if you wanted to merge just one vertex, that *is* the resulting shape, as interpolated by Catmull-Clark Subdivision.

If you wanted to merge the entire circumference, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd>  > Bridge Edge Loops, with 'Merge', is an option:

[image]

Above, the two underlying square profiles being merged are C-C subdivided to approximations of circles. (If you want more accurate circles, 6 sides is really a practical minimum)